# command line wget with visual progress bar

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

In my batch-program I'm using wget to download files in the background.  The cli is hidden from the user and I would like to be able to display the progress as a bar or at the very least in a small window as a %.
Isn't there a version of wget that does this already, or am I remembering something else?

Comment: The terminal is hidden?  And you want this program to create a window with a progress bar?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot predict the time it takes wget to do the downloading. Hence you cannot show a progress bar.

My advice is to shell the wget exe and use this [Microsoft KB link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305368) to wait for a shelled application to finish by using VB.Net

While the application is waitng for wget to finish show a ThinkingBar control, ie an animated gif in a PictureBox control *via a winform application, script, etc*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

Try to open it in form of a pipe. The output of wget should be input to your application. This seems to be the cleanest way.

If the parent process needs to be vb.net app, I don't know, how this can be done in vb.net. The vb6 implementation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386730/shell-process-standard-output-reading-in-visual-basic-6).

Or try to use [named pipes](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=871044) using vb.net.

Or, open it in form:
`wget ... | my_vb_dot_net_app.exe` from the batch script.