# Transfer contents of a variable in a .bat file to a variable in VB

Tags: batch-file, vb6

I am trying to write a VB code where a .bat file is loaded from VB then according to  the outcome of the batch file other actions are taken from VB.

For launching the .bat file from VB no probs.

My problem  comes when I need to pick the contents of a variable named status used in the .bat file and transfer it into a variable in the VB code.

Any ideas, suggestions are appreciated?

Comment: I don't have any experience with batch files, but can't you edit the batch to return the status code?

Comment: May this one could be of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7389725/4584335

Answer (score 1):

Try redirecting the results of the batch file to another file like...

```
C:\>dir *.* > result.txt
```

Where your VB app can look for (result.txt), open it read it after it's created by the .bat file

Comment: You might need your .bat to right out a second file, after result.txt.  A second file that lets your VB app know that result.txt is actually done being created.  Depending on what your .bat file is doing, result.txt could show up on your drive before it's done being written to, closed etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read the environ variables of the batchfile directly as they belong solely to that process.

Read [the comments on this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more detailed info

The only solution would be to make the batchfile store the result somewhere else where vb6 can read it like in a file or the registry.

I always like creating a section in the registry for my VB6 app and store my data there.

In a batch file you can write to the registry via the `reg add` command.

Have a look at [this post at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130193/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-registry-entry-via-a-bat-cmd-script) for some more comments on the `reg add` command